# Caesar Cipher C program - format %i expects argument of type int * but has type int

Tags: c, rotation, atoi, caesar-cipher

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>


int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{

argc++;

int number;

printf("Enter word you would like encoded\n");

scanf ("%s %i", argv[0], atoi(&argv[1]));

printf("%s", argv[1]);


int len = strlen(argv[1]);

for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
{
    char offsetWord;

    offsetWord = atoi(argv[i])+len;

    putchar(offsetWord);
}

putchar('\n');

return 0;
}
```

I am trying to make a C Caesar cipher program that compiles from a Linux command line. The requirements:

1) ./rotn

abcdef

nopqrs)

2) ./rotn dog

Gur dhvpx oebja sbk whzcf bire gur ynml qbt.

3) Writing to a file via "rotn".

./rotn dog fox

$ cat fox

Gur dhvpx oebja sbk whzcf bire gur ynml qbt.

4) using various shifts 
  ./rotn -8 dog

Bpm ycqks jzwev nwf rcuxa wdmz bpm tihg lwo.

This is as far as I've gotten. I have been bogged down with compiling errors. The one I'm having right now is "warning format %i expects argument of type int * but argument 3 has type of int.

Any suggestions?

Comment: The error occurs because `scanf` with `%i` specifier wants to read an integer from the standard input and put the value at a location that you give the pointer to. An integer pointer is type `int *`. However, you don't `scanf` the values of `argv`. You just read them and they represent the command name and command line arguments. They are already provided for you from the command line. If you want to read values in later from the user, use your own variables, not the ones passed in through `main`.

Comment: What was the purpose of `argc++;` which you don't even use (or check)?

Answer (score 1):

As already pointed out in the comments, you have mixed up a few things:

- `argc` and `argv` are the arguments passed to the program when it is called. There is always at least one argument, `argv[0]`, the name of the program. You should use this information to parse your command line.
- `scanf` scans formatted input from `stdin`. You don't really need formatted input here, you can read a whole line with `fgets` or you can read a single character with `fgetc`. You store the scanned data in new variables; don't reuse `argv` for that.

A program that interprets your command line might look like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    int shift = 13;                 // default shift
    const char *infile = NULL;      // default is stdin
    const char *outfile = NULL;     // default is stdout
    int i = 1;

    if (i < argc && argv[i][0] == '-') {
        shift = atoi(&argv[i][1]);
        if (shift <= 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Illegal shift.\n");
            exit(1);
        }
        i++;
    }

    if (i < argc) {
        infile = argv[i];
        i++;
    }

    if (i < argc) {
        outfile = argv[i];
        i++;
    }

    if (i < argc) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Illegal extra argument.\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    printf("shift: %d\n", shift);
    if (infile) printf("infile: %s\n", infile);
    if (outfile) printf("outfile: %s\n", outfile);

    // now use this inforation in your program

    return 0;
}
```

Of course, you must still implement the encoder itself. Here are some hints:

- `stdin` is a valid file handle, so you could use that if the user hasn't specified a file name or a handle returned from `fopen(infile, "r")` otherwise. You can test whether the user has specified a file name with `if (infile) ...` Remember to close the file when it isn't `stdin`, though.
- The same logic can be used for the output file, except that you must open the file in write mode `"w"` and that you should use `fprintf` or `fputc`.